# How to separate large ASP.NET MVC3 App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen different approaches to separation of MVC3 app, but most of them feel 'hacky' or require extra dependencies, like portable areas from MvcContrib. I remember there was a way to separate large app into separate modules in MVC2 Beta or RC, but in release this feature doesn't work. So is there any recommended way to separate large projects?

P.S I have seen Orchard. But its module infrastructure is a bit too complicated for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't [areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) fit your needs?

Comment: I want them in separate assemblies for modularity. Also I don't want to expose full app to contractors, so they only need to create a module that I can just drop in. Like Django apps.

Comment: That's exactly what MVContrib's portable areas offers. If you don't want to use third party libraries to achieve this you could always build it yourself but it could be a hell lot of a work for something that already exists.

Comment: AFAIK MvcContrib areas are forcing me to use their messaging infrastructure and this stops me from using them. Separating areas in different assemblies existed in Asp.Net MVC 2 before release: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx

Comment: You don't have to use the messaging infrastructure, most examples do but it is absolutely not needed at all. we aren't using it ourselves either.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying with making seperate directory and modify rewrite rule as per that. Though I haven't tried these structure on asp.net mvc, but did in php mvc frameworks, worked fine there. I myself new to asp.net mvc and will like to get best answer of this question also.

Comment: My app is multitenant and uses dynamic subdomains and etc, so it will expose some issues with auth, routing etc.